# How to know if Excel Services is available on SharePoint?

Tags: 2010, excel-services, office-web-apps

I'm using a Sharepoint 2010 server. Unfortunately, I'm not the administrator and I'm not able to connect with him. But I want to know, if Excel Services is installed and activated.

I'm able to edit an Excel file directly in the browser (Excel Web App). Does this automatically mean that Excel Services is installed?

And can I test the Excel REST API as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Admin access to SharePoint or Contact to SharePoint administrator, it little tricky to know about it.
But From Excel API you can try it.

To use the Rest API, you have to Craft the URI.

**Workbook Uploaded Location:** http://www.contoso.com/Shared Documents/Clock.xlsx.

**Then craft the REST API URI to the scatter chart named Clock**

> http://www.contoso.com/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/SharedDocuments/Clock.xlsx/Model/Charts(‘Clock’)

Follow the instruction from Office blog here:
http://blogs.office.com/2009/11/09/excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010-rest-api-examples/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cumgranosalis/archive/2009/10/27/welcome-to-the-new-excel-services.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, the Office for Web Applications (Excel) is not the same as Excel Services.  If you have both installed, the administrator would have had to run this powershell script in order to open Excel documents in the browser instead of OWA:

```
New-SPWOPISuppressionSetting -Extension "XLSX" -Action "view"
```

There are a few different methods to determine if Excel Services is working for you.  The most simplistic would be to open an Excel document that contains a Data Model.  Other methods would be to have an Excel document contain a Power Map view or Power View sheet.

The REST API will not respond without Excel services installed.